# What is the difference between Melange and Cappuccino?

Tags: brewing-process, foamed-milk

Melange is the most popular coffee beverage in Vienna, Austria and surrounding. It's preparation and look is in my humble opinion exactly the same as Cappuccino. You use an espresso shot, create some milk foam, add the hot milk together with the milk foam on top. Some will sprinkle some cocoa or cinnamon powder on top.

So is it only the name or is there any deeper difference that the customer do not see?

Answer (score 4):

Melange describes different beverages with coffee in different places. The Melange from Vienna is indeed very similar to Cappuccino. However, Melange is sometimes not produced using Espresso, but normal filter coffee.

In Switzerland, in contrast, Melange is made with whipped cream instead of milk.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_Melange probably we have to be more specific and call it Wiener Melange, as Melange means something different in other countries. What you call Melange in Switzerland is called Franziskaner in Vienna.

Answer (score 1):

There is in fact a difference which can’t always be seen:
A Viennese melange is espresso mixed with hot milk, topped of with milk foam. A Cappuccino is merely espresso topped with (a lot) of milk foam.